# How can I update my Django model using signals?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How can I keep adding to the total price, when a new instance is created in the CartItem model and also deduct the price when an item is deleted ? , at the moment my current signals is only showing the price of the current product that I update or create.

signals.py

```
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=CartItem, dispatch_uid="update_total")
def add_cart_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs): 
    total = 0
    product_price = instance.item.price
    quantity = instance.quantity
    updated_total = Decimal(product_price) * int(quantity)
    total += updated_total
    if instance.items_cart.subtotal != total:
        instance.items_cart.subtotal = total
        instance.items_cart.save()
```

models.py

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    item        = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    items_cart  = models.ForeignKey('Cart', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity    = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return 'item:{} cart:{} quantity:{}'.format(self.item, self.items_cart, self.quantity)
    

class Cart(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)  
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


    
    def __str__(self):
        return 'id:{} user:{} subtotal:{} total:{} updated:{}'.format(self.id, self.user, self.subtotal, self.total, self.updated)
```

views.py

```
def cart_add(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    try:
        product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        quantity = request.POST.get('quantity_field')
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        last_qty = CartItem.objects.filter(item=product_obj, items_cart=cart_obj).reverse()[0].delete()
        new_qty = CartItem(item=product_obj, items_cart=cart_obj, quantity=quantity) 
        new_qty.save()
        return redirect("cart:home")
    except ValueError:
        print("Unable to increase quantity")
    return redirect("cart:home")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem I was having, below is my solution, to keep accumulating the total price of all items in my current cart, I have done this by looping over a Queryset of 'cart_items' and calculating the price * quantity, then adding it to a counter ('total'),  then saving it to my 'Cart' model field 'total'. The receiver is collecting 'post_save' and 'post_delete' signals.  Hopefully this will help someone else.

signals.py

```
@receiver([post_save,post_delete], sender=CartItem, dispatch_uid="update_total")
def add_cart_receiver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    cart = instance.items_cart.id
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(items_cart=cart)
    cart_total = 0
    for element in cart_items:
        cart_total += (Decimal(element.item.price) * int(element.quantity))

    instance.items_cart.subtotal = cart_total
    instance.items_cart.save()
```